# Writing large volume of data to SD card

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, c, accelerometer, sd

I'm planning to make a data logger project with 3-axis sensor and SD card. I would like to store 3200 samples per every second on SD card. Currently I could able to store only 630 samples per second.

Someone told me writing in  binary format is the solution.

Then I did accordingly.

```
fwrite(readings,sizeof(int16_t),6,logFile);
```

I can see .bin file with more data size compared to .txt or `printf`.

How can I get the readable ASCII format from .bin file?

I tried by using `fread`.

```
FILE *logFile = fopen(fileName,"rb");
int readings[6];
nr = fread(readings,sizeof(int16_t),6,logFile);
```

How can I see the readable ASCII data?.

Thank you.

Comment: What library are you using? This isnt code from the Arduino SD library. Edit your post and show the rest of your code

Comment: You may want to change the title of your question. You ask about reading binary data from a .bin file, not writing data to a sd-card, as this works already (as I have understood).

Comment: regarding the writing of the data to the sd-card.   If you buffer the data in memory, (for instance, have a buffer that is large enough to hold 1 second of data) read the data from the sensor into the 'appropriate' location(s) in the buffer. then, switch to a second buffer for reading the data while writing the first buffer to the sd-card,   then when the second buffer is full, switch back to the first buffer for input (I.E. use double buffering) then the throughput will be massively increased

Answer (score 1):

*how can I see the readable ASCII data?*

use something similar to:

```
printf( "\n"); 
for( int i=0; i<6; i++) 
{ 
    printf("%d ", readings[i]);
}
```